# Find the centre of a circle given two points lying on it and its radius

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

We have been given 2 points on a circle and its radius. Now I want to find out the centre point of such a circle. How can I code this efficiently without solving the quadratic equations?

Comment: Wouldn't there be two possibilities?

Comment: What have you tried? Why is solving quadratic equations a problem? What are the restritions here, e.g. runtime?

Comment: @DennisMeng Yes there will be 2 possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$INPUT \rightarrow P_1(x_1, y_1), P_2(x_2,y_2), r$$
[image: How it works]
$$d=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$$
$$h=\sqrt{r^2-(\frac{d}2)^2}$$
$$\alpha=arcsin(\frac{y_1-y_2}{d})$$
$$x_c=\frac{x_1+x_2}2+h sin(\alpha)$$
$$y_c=\frac{y_1+y_2}2+h cos(\alpha)$$

Comment: That's a bunch of formulae, not an answer. Where do they come from? Why are they correct? How can they be translated into an algorithm? Which runtime will it have?

Comment: @Raphael, I added an image which describe how it works. What do you mean by runtime, please?

Comment: @Raphael This is quite basic geometry; being given the solution is more than enough in my opinion.

Comment: @G.Bach: If the point is geometry, it is offtopic here and should be on [math.SE]. The OP, however, asks "How can I code this efficiently without solving the quadratic equations?". Other than that, usual standards apply, and just giving the solution is (almost) never enough to constitute an SE-good answer.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

\begin{align*}
  \mathbf{v} &= (\mathbf{p_2} - \mathbf{p_1}) =
  \begin{pmatrix} v_x \\ v_y \end{pmatrix} \\
  h &= \sqrt{r^2 - \frac{\lvert \mathbf{v} \rvert^2}{4}} \\
  \mathbf{u_h} &= \frac{1}{\lvert \mathbf{v} \rvert}
  \begin{pmatrix} v_y \\ -v_x \end{pmatrix} \\
  c_{1,2} &= \mathbf{p_1} + \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{v} \pm h\mathbf{u_h}\\
\end{align*}

The algorithm is obvious, it's complexity should be $O(n^2)$.

Comment: What does $n$ stand for?

Comment: Any algorithm will take constant time. Without detailed costs forthe various operations the"cheapest algorithms" makes no sense.